# Reminder Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, reminder

I have a small requirement regarding a basic workflow that i want to build. What i am trying to achieve is to send a mail to the user as soon as a new item is created and then pause for a week and then send a mail again as a reminder. This happens every week on Monday, until the status of that item goes from pending to completed.

**Requirement:** To send Reminder Mail until every week until the status is Completed.

Below is the Workflow that i have created but it is not Stopping even if i change the status to completed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Transition to stage:
>
> Go End of Workflow

If you make it Go to Stage 1, it will loop infinite times.

**Update:**

> Stage: Stage 1
>
> //Your actions as it is
>
> Transition to stage:  Go to Stage 2
>
> Stage: Stage 2
>
> Pause for 7 days
>
> Transition to stage:
>
> Go to Stage 1

**Update2:**

You could write your stage 1 activity inside Loop with condition:

> Stage: Stage1
>
> Loop
>
> //provide the condition if current item status equals not completed
>
> //your actions as it is
>
> //also pause for 7 days here at the end
>
> Transition to stage:
>
> Go to End of workflow

Comment: Yes but i want to it to check again and again after a week. So, it checks again and again if the condition is right.

Comment: You could create a new stage where you would pause for a week and call stage 1 in that newly created stage.
In stage 1: Transition to new stage

Comment: could you please provide a small snip of that?

Comment: okay, but how does it know that the stage is completed and it has to stop sending reminders?

Comment: It will stop sending reminders based on the condition "If current item status not equals completed" mentioned in Stage 1

Comment: @jayantkhushalani I updated my answer, you could use loop.
Hope it helps

Comment: pause for 7 days comes underthe if condition or not?

Comment: @jayantkhushalani yes it does!
Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and upvote if it helped you